# Cannot pass arguments to a BotCallback inside a ContinueConversationAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework

I am trying to implement proactive messages on bot framework v4, It works, but only with the string on the BotCallback function, I need to pass custom text but ContinueConversationAsync doesnt seems to allow it

```
        public async Task<bool> SendProactiveMessage(MensajeExterno mensajeExterno)
    {

            var referenciaDeConversacion = ObtenerReferenciaConversacion(mensajeExterno.ConversationId);
            var continuationActivity = referenciaDeConversacion.GetContinuationActivity();
            if (referenciaDeConversacion == null) return false;


            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, referenciaDeConversacion, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));

            return true;

    }

    private ConversationReference ObtenerReferenciaConversacion(string conversationId)
    {
        return new ConversationReferenceModulo().ObtenerConversationReference(conversationId);
    }

    public MensajeroDefaultModulo(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
        {
            _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
        }
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var activity = turnContext.Activity;
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by " custom text ?"

Answer (score 8):

You can make a wrapper around BotCallback using LINQ approach. But personally i do not understand the idea of such delegates without any EventArgs.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] string messageText)
    {
        foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
        {
            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, async (context, token) => await BotCallback(messageText, context, token), default(CancellationToken));
        }

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(string message, ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understand you are wanting to do is to pass a value to the BotCallback that can be sent back via the method SendActivityAsync.

To do this you can use a lambda expression instead of calling the BotCallback.

```
public async Task<bool> SendProactiveMessage(MensajeExterno mensajeExterno)
{
        var yourVariable = "blah";

        var referenciaDeConversacion = ObtenerReferenciaConversacion(mensajeExterno.ConversationId);
        var continuationActivity = referenciaDeConversacion.GetContinuationActivity();
        if (referenciaDeConversacion == null) return false;


        await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, referenciaDeConversacion, async (context, token) => { 
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello " + yourVariable, cancellationToken: cancellationToken); 
}, default(CancellationToken));
        return true;
}
```

This comes from this reference to a proactive messaging sample here:
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/787

For Lambda expressions see [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain
>   expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or
>   expression tree types.
>
> All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as
>   "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or
>   statement block. The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x
>   times x."

**Updated with API controller example**

The SendProactiveMessage needs to be in a Controller in your Bot project, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ProactiveBot.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/notify")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
    public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"];

        // If the channel is the Emulator, and authentication is not in use,
        // the AppId will be null.  We generate a random AppId for this case only.
        // This is not required for production, since the AppId will have a value.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
        {
            _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery(Name = "taskID")] int taskID)
    {            

        foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
        {                

            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, async (context, token) => {
                await context.SendActivityAsync("proactive task notification for TaskID: " + taskID.ToString());
            }, default(CancellationToken));
        }


        // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1><p>" + taskID.ToString() + "</p></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }

}
```

}

You can then get access to the context and token through the injected adapter. The above code is largely from the current [Proactive Message sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)

So I can then call this API eg. http://localhost:3988/api/notify?taskID=5678 passing in the taskID parameter (in my case) which is then sent through to the user via ContinueConversationAsync.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, the issue here is that I dont have neither the turnContext or the cancellationToken. The method "SendProactiveMessage" is called by an API, how can that be solved? I tried Dependency Injection but wasnt able to do it

Comment: @TheMemebot Is your SendProactiveMessage method not within a Controller your Bot project?

Comment: I will try your updated solution and I will be back to you to let you know if that works. Yes, my method is inside my bot project

Comment: @TheMemebot any luck with this?